# Multilingual form in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I need to create an admin form which need to store input for different languages. How to create multilingual form in Drupal 8? Do we need to extend the core functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with hook_form_alter or language_field. Drupal 8 doesn't support webform / form translations (yet ;) ).